# How to kill or Terminate a boost Thread

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, boost, boost-thread

I want to terminate or kill boost thread.
code is here:

```
DWORD WINAPI  StartFaceDetector(LPVOID temp)
{   
    int j=0;
    char **argv1;
    QApplication a(j,argv1);//add some thread here  
    gui::VisualControl w;
    t=&w;
    boost::thread u(&faceThread);       
    w.show();
    a.exec();
    // I Want to close u thread here.   
    return 0;   
}
```

I want to close that boost thread before return of function. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why are you not using QThread?

Answer (score 15):

On Windows:

```
TerminateThread(u.native_handle(), 0);
```

On Linux / QNX / UNIX / any platform with pthread support:

```
pthread_cancel(u.native_handle());
```

or

```
pthread_kill(u.native_handle(), 9);
```

Note that boost authors intentionally left this out as the behaviour is platform-dependent and not well defined.  However, you're not the only one to ever reach for this functionality...

Answer (score 14):

Use [`interrupt()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.interrupt). Also, you should define [interruption points](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#interruption_points). Thread will be interrupted after calling `interrupt()` as soon as it reaches one of interruption points.

```
u.interrupt();
```

[More info](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/thread-interruption-in-boost-thread-library.html):

> Calling `interrupt()` just sets a flag in the thread management structure for that thread and returns: it doesn't wait for the thread to actually be interrupted. This is important, because a thread can only be interrupted at one of the predefined interruption points, and it might be that a thread never executes an interruption point, so never sees the request. Currently, the interruption points are:
>
> - `boost::thread::join()`
> - `boost::thread::timed_join()`
> - `boost::condition_variable::wait()`
> - `boost::condition_variable::timed_wait()`
> - `boost::condition_variable_any::wait()`
> - `boost::condition_variable_any::timed_wait()`
> - `boost::this_thread::sleep()`
> - `boost::this_thread::interruption_point()`

Comment: Excellent answer. To lend some context: there is no way to reliably kill a thread; not even with a platform specific facility like [`TerminateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx) without destabilizing the entire process. Cooperative is the only way.

Comment: indeed even the platform API specifically mentions that TerminateThread is a final-resort type of operation kind of like a plane having to ditch in water vs. landing on a runway