# How to stop the thread execution in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads, mutex

I created one thread in my main program, thread execution has to stop once the main program will terminate. I am using `reader.join();` to terminate the thread execution. But it is not stopping the execution.

I tried with below-mentioned code, I am using `thread.join();` function, but it is failed to terminate a thread. And after the main program also my thread is kept executing.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <cstdint>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

typedef pair<int, Mat> pairImage;

class PairComp {
public:
    bool operator()(const pairImage& n1, const pairImage& n2) const
    {
        if (n1.first == n2.first)
            return n1.first > n2.first;
        return n1.first > n2.first;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    mutex mtxQueueInput;
    queue<pairImage> queueInput;
    int total = 0;
    atomic<bool> bReading(true);
    thread reader([&]() {
        int idxInputImage = 0;
        while (true) {
            Mat img = imread("img_folder/");
            mtxQueueInput.lock();
            queueInput.push(make_pair(idxInputImage++, img));
            if (queueInput.size() >= 100) {
                mtxQueueInput.unlock();
                cout << "[Warning]input queue size is " << queueInput.size();
                // Sleep for a moment
                sleep(2);
            }
            else {
                mtxQueueInput.unlock();
            }
        }
        bReading.store(false);
    });

    while (true) {
        pair<int, Mat> pairIndexImage;
        mtxQueueInput.lock();
        if (queueInput.empty()) {
            mtxQueueInput.unlock();
            if (bReading.load())
                continue;
            else
                break;
        }
        else {
            // Get an image from input queue
            pairIndexImage = queueInput.front();
            queueInput.pop();
        }
        mtxQueueInput.unlock();
        cv::Mat frame = pairIndexImage.second;

        cv::rectangle(frame, cv::Rect{ 100, 100, 100, 100 }, 0xff);
    }

    cv::imshow("out_image", frame);
    waitKey(1);

    if (total++ == 200)
        break;

    if (reader.joinable()) {
        reader.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To improve you question, you could shorten your code example to make it more readable =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`thread.join()` does not cause the thread to terminate, it waits until the thread ends. It's the responsibility of the thread to end its execution, for example by periodically checking for a certain condition, like a flag.

You already have an `atomic` flag `bReading`, which appears to cause the thread to exit.

```
        if (queueInput.empty()) {
            mtxQueueInput.unlock();
            if (bReading.load())
                continue;
            else
                break;  // thread will exit when queue is empty and bReading == false
```

So all you need is to set `bReading = false` **in the outer thread** before calling `thread.join()`.

```
bReading = false;
reader.join();
```

Note that `bReading.store(false);` inside your thread will have no effect.

---

Note: you don't need to call `atomic.load()` and `atomic.store()`, you can just use them in your code, which will call `load()` and `store()` implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of an built in possibility to stop a `thread`. Since you have a `endless-loop` embedded in your thread, it won't stop at any time.

`std::thread::join` does not terminate your thread. You have to implement something to end your loop, when you demand it.

- A `bool` variable you set `false` when the `thread` has to exit. e.g. `while(run)` or something like that; for simplicity you could also use a `std::atomic<bool>`
- A signaling variable you check. `std::condition_variable`

What you do at the moment is, you wait in your `main-thread` that your `thread` terminates. Since `std::thread::join` does't terminate your `thread`, your `main-thread` will execute forever.

NOTE: When you choose to implement the `bool` solution. You should protect this `bool` with an `mutex` or something alike.

Thanks for the comment. As I don't want to point everyone to `boost`, but you mentioned it. Find information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558875/how-to-kill-or-terminate-a-boost-thread).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher thanks, I linked a answered question in my answer

Comment: Re, "I'm not aware of an built in possibility to stop a thread." There's a reason for that: There is _no safe way_ for one thread to stop another. Not in any language, not on any system. It's because of the nature of threads: They operate on shared data, and there is never any way to know whether some other thread is halfway done with updating some shared data such that, if you forced it to stop at that moment, it would leave the data in a corrupt state. Threads must always _cooperate_ with each other. If you want thread S to stop, then you must design-in a way to _ask_ it to stop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `join` which (btw) is not meant to be used to stop or terminate a thread.

The function that your thread is executing contains a `while(true)` which will never terminate, because it can only sleep and unlock the lock, nothing else.

This means that `bReading.store` will never be called and as a consequence in the main thread loop you will always go though this branch of the is

```
if (bReading.load())
        continue;
```

meaning that also the `main` will execute forever.

---

`std::join` is used to wait from a thread that another thread has completed its work. when you do `thread1.join()` from the `main` thread what happens is that `main` will **wait** until `thread1` has completed its execution before executing any other instruction.